# Trouble with Scholar Package (scholar::get_article_cite_history)

Tags: r, google-scholar

I'm trying to load citation history of a journal article using the scholar package, and as far as I can tell I'm using the correct format and syntax, though the resulting output is an empty data frame.

Example below should run as is. I'd like to load the citation history of "Data-driven asthma endotypes defined from blood biomarker and gene expression data", an article for which I've pulled the author and article id.

```
library(scholar)

id <- '0853ilkAAAAJ&hl'

all_pubs <- get_publications(id)

all_pubs$title

all_pubs %>% 
  filter(title == "Data-driven asthma endotypes defined from blood biomarker and gene expression data") %>% 
  select (pubid)

article <- 'M05iB0D1s5AC'

humpf <- get_article_cite_history(id, article)
```

This resulting output is a an empty data frame with the 3 collect column headers (year, cites, pubid). The expected result should populate this data frame with the information of the 24 articles which have cited this one.